# Refactoring respond_to? call in if-elsif-else condition

Tags: ruby

I have the following method and want to make it more readable:

```
def value_format(value)
  if value.respond_to? :to_actor
    value.to_actor
  elsif value.respond_to? :to_subject
    value.to_subject
  elsif value.respond_to? :to_json
    value.to_json
  elsif value.respond_to? :to_hash
    value.to_hash
  else
    value.inspect
  end
end
```

This is my solution. What do you think?

```
def value_format(value)
  methods = [:to_actor, :to_subject, :to_json, :to_hash, :inspect]
  value.send(methods.find_all { |m| m if value.respond_to? m }.first)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution looks fine, but you might as well use `find` instead of `find_all`:

```
METHODS = [:to_actor, :to_subject, :to_json, :to_hash, :inspect]
def value_format(value)
  value.send(METHODS.find { |m| value.respond_to? m })
end
```

Using a constant has the advantage of not creating a new array every time `value_format` is ran.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there's a pretty simple optimization to your solution:

```
def value_format(value)
  methods = [:to_actor, :to_subject, :to_json, :to_hash]
  value.send(methods.find(:inspect) { |m| value.respond_to? m })
end
```

Comment: He he, same idea, same time. Note that `find`'s argument has to be a `Proc` or `lambda`.

Comment: @Marc-André Lafortune: Your answer was slightly earlier.  Also, I didn't realize that about the argument to `find`...  I'd consider your version better.

Answer (score 0):

The facets gem provides an elegant solution (I think) to this problem. It combines the two steps of checking if an object responds to a method and actually calling that method into a single step.

So your example could be rewritten as this:

```
require 'facets/kernel/respond'

def value_format(v)
  v.respond.to_actor || v.respond.to_subject || v.respond.to_json || v.respond.to_hash || v.respond.inspect
end
```

Note that this method only works if it is safe to assume that none of these methods are going to return `nil` or `false` (because `respond` returns `nil` if the object doesn't respond, that is what allows us to chain it together with a bunch of `or`s).

Since all of the methods you listed should return strings, I believe this approach would work fine in your example.

[Documentation](http://rubyworks.github.com/rubyfaux/?doc=http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/docs/facets-2.9.3/core.json#api-module-Kernel/api-method-Kernel-h-respond):

```
  # Like #respond_to? but returns the result of the call
  # if it does indeed respond.
  #
  #   class RespondExample
  #     def f; "f"; end
  #   end
  #
  #   x = RespondExample.new
  #   x.respond(:f)  #=> "f"
  #   x.respond(:g)  #=> nil
  #
  # or
  #
  #   x.respond.f   #=> "f"
  #   x.respond.g   #=> nil
```